# Displaying Random Row from SQL Database

Tags: php, sql

I have been working for days now and I am at a dead end.  After talking with GoDaddy support I am positive that I have the correct hostname, username/password when I run the script but it still cannot get past `die()`.

Ultimately I am attempting to pull a single question from a database.  I have combed this website but nothing i found seems to answer my question.  Please help.

```
<?php
    $hostname='localhost';
    $username='username';
    $password='password';
    $dbname='qod';
    $usertable='Questions';
    $userfield='question';

    mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) or die ("<html><script language='JavaScript'>alert('Unable to access the Question of the Day! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script></html>");
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    # Check If Record Exists

    $query = 'SELECT $.userfield FROM $.usertable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if($result){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $name = $row[$yourfield];
        echo "Name: ".$name;}
    }
?>
```

Comment: You have dots in `$.userfield $.usertable` any special reason? Your variables have none, therefore it should most likely be `SELECT $userfield FROM $usertable`. Plus `.$name` should be `$name` and `$yourfield` is a stray variable which should most likely be without the dollar sign.

Comment: Instead of some fancy JS, why don't you check the error log in your `die()` statement?

Comment: In your die message put ".mysql_error() at the end and it should give you the connection error. $link = mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password); or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

Comment: mysql_* is going away.  What's the print_r($dbh->errorInfo());?  What is the or die outputting?

Comment: Sidenote: I made a mistake about the `.$name` my bad. I couldn't edit my comment on time, but the rest still stands.

Answer (score 2):

You are using dots for your SELECT variables where there shouldn't be any.

`SELECT $.userfield FROM $.usertable`, then calling them with:

```
$usertable='Questions';
$userfield='question';
```

**Remove them** from your SELECT and use proper [***error reporting***](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) techniques such as :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// rest of code
```

and

```
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
```

also a dollar sign in `[$yourfield]` for your column name; remove it also.

You should be using quotes: I.e.: `['yourfield']` - `yourfield` being the column name in your table that you wish to show.

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).